# Array Bidimensional JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loop

Olá, tenho um array bidimensional da seguinte forma

```
var array= [[{"id": 23, "nome": "Daniel"},
    {"id": 24, "nome": "Bruno"},
    {"id": 25, "nome": "Guilherme"}],
    [{"id": 1, "nome": "Luiz"}],
    [{"id": 2, "nome": "Miguel"},
     {"id" :3, "nome": "Matheus"}]]
```

Preciso imprimir ele da seguinte maneira

```
[{id: 23, nome: Daniel},{id: 1, nome: Luiz},{id: 2, nome: Miguel},
{id: 24, nome: Bruno},{id: 1, nome: Luiz},{id: 3, nome: Matheus},
{id: 25, nome: Guilherme},{id: 1, nome: Luiz},{id: 2, nome: Miguel}]
```

Porem só consegui algo como

```
[{"id":23,"nome":"Daniel"},{"id":24,"nome":"Bruno"},{"id":25,"nome":"Guilherme"},{"id":1,"nome":"Luiz"},{"id":2,"nome":"Miguel"},{"id":3,"nome":"Matheus"}]
```

Fiz da seguinte maneira:

```
for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){  
        for(k = 0; k < array[i].length; k++){
            console.log(array[i][k]);
        }
    }
```

Alguem pode me dar uma luz?

Comment: Duas perguntas: `1)` Porque queres que apareçam elementos da array duplicados? qual é a lógica? `2)` qual é o código que tentaste? podes juntá-lo à pergunta?

Comment: No caso acima é só um exemplo, mas eu preciso para um projeto de slides no qual estou trabalhando, onde cada linha seria um cliente, e um cliente pode ou não ter 2 ou mais slides e preciso passar um slide por vez nos clientes que tiverem mais de 1 slide.

Comment: Ok, então o que queres é fazer um `flatten`... mover elementos de arrays aninhadas dentro de arrays para o primeiro nível da array inicial. Correto?

Comment: Mas dessa forma ele imprimiria uma vez cada objeto né? desculpa se estiver dizendo bobagem.

Comment: Só fazendo `flatten` ele não limpa duplicados.

Comment: Dá um exemplo exato da array final que queres. Como está não percebo a lógica... porque é que "Luiz" aparece 3 vezes quando só há 1 na array inicial?

Comment: Perceba que na primeira linha eu tenho 3 colunas, na segunda eu tenho 1 coluna, preciso passar em todas as linhas e pegar uma coluna por vez, onde tiver mais de 1 coluna não ira repetir, onde tiver apenas 1 ira repetir.